# How can Highslide Js dimmer blur the background as well?

Tags: highslide

Can somebody please tell me if it is possible and how to blur the background using the dimming option in "Highslide JS", I know it might  not work with some browsers but I am still willing to give it a try. Secondly, can someonbe tell me how to trigger the dimmer on mouse click and not on pop up image load as is the default.

Thanks for Your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your second question, do you just want the background to dim instantly, instead of gradually? If so, try:

```
hs.dimmingDuration = 0;
```

Truly triggering the dimming before the image expansion occurs requires some hacking of highslide-full.js. You'll have to do some tinkering. You need to move this:

```
if (this.dimmingOpacity) hs.dim(this);
```

From the afterExpand() function to the show() function.

Comment: BTW, the regular Highslide forums are back - you should probably start posting there, instead of here: http://forum.highcharts.com

Comment: And when you do post here, don't tag the question with anything other than "highslide." If you do, the SO regulars will close the question because they don't understand it. Better that they don't see it at all.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips I will try them out. Yeah sure, I will ask arroud there. I wasn't aware about the tagging part, I will be more mindful in the future, thanks again for you swift reply :)

Comment: Hey just wanted to let You know I did exactly as you suggested and it work perfectly, You really know your stuff :), just one thing I did differently, instead of highslide-full.js. I changed the code in highslide-with-gallery.js, because it didn't work when I changed it in the first one. Now I just need to figure out how to write the js code for background blur effect on dimming.

Comment: It probably didn't work when you changed highslide-full.js because your page was still loading highslide-with-gallery.js. I would always use highslide-full.js, which is the full script, with all of the capabilities. The others, like highslide-with-gallery.js, are just subsets of the full script, and may not contain the routines needed to make other things work. The full script is smaller than a typical single image, so there's really no penalty for loading the whole thing.

Comment: BTW, I don't really know Javascript, but your question was familiar, and I managed to find an old post from Torstein suggesting that approach.

Comment: Ok, got it. I changed it too as you said. Ha :), well I am happy you have such a good memory, and took the time to answer my question.

Comment: Hey, jsut wanted to let you know I have been blacklisted on Highchart for spamming :), so I will respond to your post here, since it is the same topic ...  Hey again, I am glad I bumped into You :). OK, so if it does that for the color dim, can it do the same with the blur dim, for example overlay a div that has the blur css attached to it, and opacity reduced; or even better yet, can I add the blur css to the existing background color div you mentioned, that the dimming puts there?

Comment: I understand probably chrome is the only browser that can view this, but I don't care, I mean in the future maybe more browsers will , and it can be a treat for the people using chrome. 
I wrote a suggestion letter to the Highslide JS team, and they said they will discuss adding this option to the Highslide JS editor, I mean for now this is the best I can do, since I am not a programmer myself and wouldn't know how to help them achieve this. Hope for the best.

Comment: You can add whatever CSS you like to the .highslide-dimming class in highslide.css. I use it, for example, to provide a background image file (a texture, e.g.), rather than a solid color. But again, that will not apply to the body of the page - it will blur() the image file you're using for the dimming div, but the page behind it would still be sharp. Overlays are not like eyeglasses.

Comment: Ok, yeah you are right it will only blur that div, and will not affect the actual background.

Comment: Hey again! I would like to ask for your help if you are willing, I got a reply to the blur option on Highchart, as you might have seen, just havning some trouble with placing the java script I got, do you know where I should put it? http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/t49HJ/

Comment: Put the Javascript into your highslide-config.js file, or, if you're not using one, put it into the <head> section of your page, AFTER you've loaded highslide-full.js (since it's modifying stuff that's in there).